# Zingchart not pulling data from MariaDB

Tags: php, html, mysql, zingchart

I am trying to build some ZingCharts with weatherdata from a homemade weatherstation. Currently I am using Google Charts, but would rather use Zing as it seems a whole lot easier to work with. Except, I can't get it to pull data from my Database. Below I have the demo example from ZingChart git, all I did was change the variables concerning my sql server. But it just shows an empty page. Looking at the page source after loading reveals that it doesn't fill the arrays with any data at all.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>MySQL Demo</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.zingchart.com/zingchart.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
<script>

<?php
    $host = "localhost";         
    $port = 3306;
    $usernm = "pi";
    $passwd = "";
    $dbname = "weatherDB";
    $query = "SELECT timestamp, temperature from bme680 ORDER BY id ASC";

    $time = []; 
    $temperature = []; 
    $mysqli = new mysqli($host, $usernm, $passwd, $dbname, $port);
    if($mysqli->connect_error) {
          die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ')' . $mysqli->connect_error);
    }

    if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
        while( $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)){
            array_push($time, $row[0]);
            array_push($temperature, $row[1]);
        }

        $result->close();
    }
?>
      var dateValues = [<?php echo join($time, ',') ?>];
      var seriesValues = [<?php echo join($temperature, ',') ?>];
<?php
    $mysqli->close(); 
?>
</script>
<script>
window.onload=function(){
  zingchart.render({
    id:"myChart",
    width:"100%",
    height:400,
    data:{
      "type":"line",
      "title":{"text":"Data Pulled from MySQL Database"},
      "scale-x":{
            "values": dateValues,
            "transform":{
                "type":"date",
                "item":{
                    "visible":false
                }
            }
      },
      "plot":{"line-width":1},
      "series":[ {"values":seriesValues}]
    }
  });
};
</script>
    <h1>Database Data</h1>
    <div id="myChart"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You said, I think that you have an SQLServer database, is that right?

Comment: I have MariaDB running on the same machine as the webserver, and as I wrote, it pulls fine and shows as supposed in my Google Charts. The php query is also nearly idetical.

Comment: Might be useful to see the original unchanged code you got from GIT so we can see what you changed and sanity check it

Comment: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/zingchart-demos/php-mysql/master/index.php

Comment: I think you are still going to have to convert the timestamp to a numeric, when you select from MySQL it will come back to you as a `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss` and not a unix timestamp like 7652345

Comment: Already tried that.

Comment: Did you check the Browser debugger Console for any useful hints and error messages

Comment: It complains over line 50:

            "values": dateValues,

That dateValues is not defined, but it gets defined 10 lines up here:

      var dateValues = [<?php echo join($time, ',') ?>];

Comment: So can you find that in the debugger! Does it really exist as far as javascript is concerned